# Why are Blazor pages not firing in my ASP.Net app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-blazor

I'm writing an ASP.Net Core app based on Freeman's book.
And while adding Blazor pages, I got a problem. When you try to go to pages that Blazor is connected to, nothing is displayed on them.

The browser console shows these errors:

> Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router.Refresh(Boolean
> isNavigationIntercepted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView
> parameters)

My Routed.razor file:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly"
    AdditionalAssemblies="new[]{typeof(Program).Assembly}">
<Found>
    <RouteView RouteData="@context" DefaultLayout="typeof(AdminLayout)" />
</Found>
<NotFound>
    <h4 class="bg-danger text-white text-center p-2">
        No Matching Route Found
    </h4>
</NotFound>
```

What could be the problem?

I also add a link to the repository of my project:

https://github.com/itehnoviking/CoinStore

Comment: What URL gives you the error you reported above? What happens when you navigate to `/admin/orders`?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis /admin    But when going to admin/orders, the error is exactly the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to "Hack" your `Program` to get your solution running.  Here's my version:

```
using CoinStore.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CoinStore
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<StoreDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            builder.Services.AddScoped<IStoreRepository, EFStoreRepository>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IOrderRepository, EFOrderRepository>();
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
            builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            builder.Services.AddSession();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<Cart>(sp => SessionCart.GetCart(sp));
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            //builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

            //builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(o => {
            //    o.DetailedErrors = _env.IsDevelopment;
            //}).AddHubOptions(opt => {
            //    opt.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB
            //});

            builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options => { options.DetailedErrors = true; });





            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            //app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            //    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("catpage",
            //        "{category}/Page{productPage:int}",
            //        new { Controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

            //    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("page", "Page{productPage:int}",
            //        new { Controller = "Home", action = "Index", productPage = 1 });

            //    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("category", "{category}",
            //        new { Controller = "Home", action = "Index", productPage = 1 });

            //    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("pagination",
            //        "Products/Page{productPage}",
            //        new { Controller = "Home", action = "Index", productPage = 1 });
            //    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            //    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            //    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            //    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/admin/{*catchall}", "/Admin/Index");
            //});


            //app.MapControllerRoute("catpage", "{category}/Page{productPage:int}", new { controller = "Home", action = "index" });
            //app.MapControllerRoute("page", "Page{productPage:int}", new { controller = "Home", action = "index", productPage = 1 });
            //app.MapControllerRoute("category", "{category}", new { controller = "Home", action = "index", productPage = 1 });
            //app.MapControllerRoute("pagination", "Products/Page{productPage}", new { controller = "Home", action = "index", productPage = 1 });

            //app.MapControllerRoute(
            //    name: "default",
            //    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            //app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            app.MapRazorPages();
            app.MapBlazorHub();
            app.MapFallbackToPage("/admin/{*catchall}", "/Admin/Index");
            


            //SeedData.EnsurePopulated(app);

            app.Run();

        }
    }
}
```

I then update Routed.razor - no duplication of assemblies any more which was the main issue.

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found>
        <RouteView RouteData="@context" DefaultLayout="typeof(AdminLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <h4 class="bg-danger text-white text-center p-2">
            No Matching Route Found
        </h4>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

And a quick fix to Index to get the references correct:

```
@page "/admin"
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CoinStore Admin</title>
        <link href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <base href="~/" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <component type="typeof(Routed)" render-mode="Server" />
        <script src="/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I get:

[image]

Comment: Good day! When the Program class was changed, other pages of the site that were not on Blazor stopped working. But if you make changes only in Index and Routed - the site works completely! Thanks a lot!